# AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute 'manager' when test spynner

Tags: python, spynner

I'm trying to use spynner to auto-click some button in the HTML source code as a small test. But I'm receiving this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\spynner\browser.py", line 287, in _on_reply
AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute 'manager'

Below is my code, which is following the guide here:https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner/blob/master/examples/webkit_methods.py

```
import spynner
import libxml2

proxy_ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
browser = spynner.Browser()  

    # setting proxy ip  
browser.set_proxy(proxy_ip :'8080'); 
browser.show() 

try:  
        browser.load(url='http://xxx.html', load_timeout=10, tries=1)  
except spynner.SpynnerTimeout:  
        print 'Timeout.'  
else:  

        browser.wk_click('a[id="voteProjectBtn_10353150"]', wait_load=True)  
browser.close()
```

I'm using Python 2.7, thanks for the help!

Comment: can you share the full error?  at no point in the above code do I see where you try to access Browser.manager, so it's hard to say with certainty what the error is.

Comment: The whole error information is here: browser.load("xxx.html") 
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\spynner\browser.py", line 548, in load
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\spynner\browser.py", line 440, in _wait_load
spynner.browser.SpynnerTimeout: Timeout reached: 10 seconds

Comment: Having the same issue. I use Browser.load(xx) and only with some sites do I get the AttributeError. There is an issue for that on the Github page, which is still open

Answer (score -1):

before `browser.close()`, you must distroy the loop javascript, some website has timming script, so you need distroy these script
see the browser.py, change the method "_manager_create_request" ,
before `browser.close()`, set `self.closeflag = True`

```
def _manager_create_request(self, operation, request, data):
    if self.closeflag:
        return None
    url = unicode(request.url().toString())
    operation_name = self._operation_names[operation].upper()
    self._debug(INFO, "Request: %s %s" % (operation_name, url))
    for h in request.rawHeaderList():
        self._debug(DEBUG, "  %s: %s" % (h, request.rawHeader(h)))
    if self._url_filter:
        if self._url_filter(self._operation_names[operation], url) is False:
            self._debug(INFO, "URL filtered: %s" % url)
            request.setUrl(QUrl("about:blank"))
        else:
            self._debug(DEBUG, "URL not filtered: %s" % url)
    reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self.manager,
        operation, request, data)
    return reply
```